# Gitlab artifact isnt created

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

i have the following `.gitlab.yaml` file

```
stages:
 - build
 - test

compile:
 stage:build
 script:
 - stuff_happening

test_1:
 stage: test
 script:
 - do_something_1
 artifacts:
  when: on_failure
  name: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  paths:
  - /root/dir
```

When `test_1` is executed , it creates a folder `dir` inside `root`
I want to add it to artifacts but , i get an error saying:
`no matching files`. If I add  `- ls root` in  the job , I can see the folder.

There is an open [question](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/907) in support forum, but still no response there.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are trying to upload files that are outside of the project's scope.

From the official [documentation on artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifacts):

> You can only use paths that are within the project workspace.

The reason is obvious; if a git runner were allowed to upload anything outside its workspace, it would cause a serious security issues.

However, if you really wanted to upload anything outside the runner's workspace, you might want to try copying the files outside into the project's root folder, and uploading it from there.

The git runners are usually registered as `user:group git-runner:git-runner` and so it will likely require `sudo privilege` if you wanted it to copy files from `/root`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have found out a way to overcome my problem. I created a symlink to the created dir inside the build folder

Comment: The reason is far from obvious, and the upload could be done from the git-runner user for instance to avoid security issues. It is rather a bad design..
Consider the use-case of incremental builds where the build directory is in "/cache" (which per-default is mounted as a docker volume and is persistent across builds). There it is perfectly normal to have the build artifacts outside the repository.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifacts

You can try adding an additional slash after your path.

```
paths:
- /root/dir/
```

Examples from the link above:

> Send all files in binaries and .config:
>
> ```
> artifacts:
>   paths:
>   - binaries/
>   - .config
> ```